# How to create number field unique list using javascript?

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin

I am creating lists from javascript in my app.
Now I want to create a Field in that with unique values which is a number field.

I am using following code:

```
var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

var f2 = context.castTo(
                accordionList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='AccordionOrder' Name='AccordionOrder' Required='True' Indexed='True' EnforceUniqueValues='True'/>", true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
                SP.FieldNumber);
f2.set_title("AccordionOrder");
f2.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessFieldAdd, onFail);
```

But when the code is getting executed it gives me error like:

> This field must be indexed to enforce unique values

How can I create this field unique? I have put `Indexed='True'` in the code. But it is not working.
Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

I am basically creating the field first and then setting the enforceUniqueValues property:

```
var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

var f2 = context.castTo(
                accordionList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml("<Field Type='Number' DisplayName='AccordionOrder' Name='AccordionOrder' Required='True' />", true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
                SP.FieldNumber);
f2.set_title("AccordionOrder");
f2.set_required(true);
f2.set_indexed(true);
f2.set_enforceUniqueValues(true);
f2.update();
context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessFieldAdd, onFail);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. But  it is not working I tried. I am still able to enter two same number in list item. :(

Comment: I tried the same code just updated `f2.set_enforceUniqueValues(true);` and the same error occured.

Comment: Just had a look at the XML dfinition for field element and turn out there is no "EnforceUniqueValues" property. The XML property you are looking for is "AllowDuplicateValues = false". See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx

Comment: Yes sir, But I found the answer from your code only. I am posting my answer.

Comment: Can you check if the new code in my answer works? I am basically trying to make it more performance effective by making only one call to the server. Also, if my answer helped you, you can mark it as answer. This will increase your acceptance rating and people will be more inclined to help you in the future.

Comment: You have just copied my answer. Anyway I have upvoted your previous answer then you update it.

Comment: If you see carefully, I have used only one executeQueryAsync statement. That's the major difference I was talking about. So instead of making two calls to the server, I am making only one call.